# MSXML2.XSLTemplate documentation

Tags: msxml

I can't find any documentation regarding this line of ASP classic code;

```
Set objTemplate = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.6.0")
```

The line is from this Microsoft page;

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762312(VS.85).aspx
```

Specifically, I can't find any info regarding "MSXML2.XSLTemplate". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objTemplate` is a COM object that supports the [IXSLTemplate interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767644.aspx).

You can use it by setting the [stylesheet property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754526.aspx) to a DOM document object loaded from your XSLT and then calling the [createProcessor method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753809.aspx) to return an object that supports the [IXSLProcessor interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762799.aspx).

Comment: Great, thank you. And particularly thanks for the summary. I don't think I could have worked that out from the Microsoft documentation.